# How to pass through arguments

Tags: ruby

Can I create method that passes any combination of position and keyword parameters to another method?

This version not working in all cases:

```
def proxy(*args, **keywords)
  send(yield, *args, **keywords)
end

def foo1(param)
  puts 'foo1', param
end

def foo2(params:)
  puts 'foo2', params
end

def foo3(param, params:)
  puts 'foo3', param, params
end

def foo4()
  puts 'foo4'
end


proxy('param') { 'foo1' } #1
proxy(params: 'params') { 'foo2' } #2
proxy('param', params: 'params') { 'foo3' } #3
proxy { 'foo4' } #4
```

#2 and #3 are working.

#1 raises `wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) (ArgumentError)`

#4 raises `wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) (ArgumentError)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
def proxy(*args)
  send(yield, *args)
end

[24] pry(main)> proxy('param') { 'foo1' } #1
foo1
param
=> nil
[25] pry(main)> proxy(params: 'params') { 'foo2' } #2
foo2
params
=> nil
[26] pry(main)> proxy('param', params: 'params') { 'foo3' } #3
foo3
param
params
=> nil
[27] pry(main)> proxy { 'foo4' } #4
foo4
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using two different types of arguments above, keyword arguments and positional arguments. A good description of the difference can be found at:

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments

Using the example they give:

```
def mysterious_total(subtotal, tax, discount)
  subtotal + tax - discount
end

mysterious_total(100, 10, 5) # => 105
```

The above is a valid method, however when you're calling it, you don't really know which place to put the arguments without looking at the definition of the method itself. If you put subtotal and tax the wrong way around, you'll get the wrong result. Keyword arguments prevent this by stating the name of the argument:

```
def obvious_total(subtotal:, tax:, discount:)
  subtotal + tax - discount
end

obvious_total(subtotal: 100, tax: 10, discount: 5) # => 105
```

This in my opinion is the far better approach, though not every ruby coder agrees.  This way, you can rearrange your arguments without breaking the method, and the method makes sense wherever you read it. If you want to some of these optional, you can do the following:

```
def obvious_total(subtotal: 100, tax: 10, discount: 5)
  subtotal + tax - discount
end
```

If you now just call `obvious_total` without any arguments, it will use the default arguments you've provided, and you can call it with just one argument, `obvious_total(subtotal: 200)`
Doing this using placement arguments is much harder, as the code doesn't know which argument you're missing. Using the first example:

```
def mysterious_total(subtotal = 100, tax = 10, discount = 5)
  subtotal + tax - discount
end
```

if I just call `mysterious_total(100)`, the system doesn't know which argument I'm missing out

Finally, it's bad practice to mix positional and keyword arguments within the same method definition. Further reading:

https://makandracards.com/makandra/36011-ruby-do-not-mix-optional-and-keyword-arguments

Answer (score 0):

for anyone coming after me, this:

```rb
def proxy(...)
  send(yield, ...)
end
```

is valid since ruby 2.7